# Shiny output not enclosed in tags - is it possible?

Tags: jquery, r, shiny

I want to output a string *not enclosed in tags* using shiny, e.g. create `<title>` content. Example:

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$mytitle <- renderText("Hello World")
})
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
    #tags$title(textOutput("mytitle")) 
    #tags$title(uiOutput("mytitle")) 
    tags$head(htmlOutput("mytitle", container = tags$title)) 
))
```

In every case shiny outputs things enclosed in some tags (generally `<div>` or `<span>`). Is it possible to output untagged string (text directly in `<body>`)? Is it possible to set `<title>` using shiny?

I understand that it uses jQuery to dynamically input content into HTML tags, however this behaviour possible to obtain in jQuery, so I am interested if it is so in shiny?

Comment: Do you mean to have `tags$title` instead of `tags$head` for the `htmlOutput` line?

Comment: @MatthewPlourde no, `tags$title` in this case would create double `<title>` tags while `tags$head` puts `<title>` in `<head>` section.

Comment: some of the ui elements have a `title=` argument (such as `navbarPage`) and I guess you could put reactive content there - would that get at what you want or are you looking for a more general functionality?

Comment: This doesn't address your more general question whether it's possible to inject untagged text into the DOM (which I don't believe it is), but if you want to just set the title element, why not supply the full title element to `renderUI`?

Comment: @JohnPaul passing text from output$ to title arguments also produces output enclosed in tags... you can only pass static (fixed) strings to such arguments rather then dynamic (as far as I know).